# How to cast into generic base class

Tags: c#, generics

I have few classes which inherits from a generic class like `FooBasePolicy<TFooTarget>`. And I want to cast my derived classes by their base class (not sure if its right way to say it). My classes are:

```
public class FooTarget{}

public class GTeamTarget : FooTarget{}

public class MTeamTarget : FooTarget{}

public class FooBasePolicy{}

public class FooBasePolicy<TFooTarget> : FooBasePolicy where TFooTarget : FooTarget
{
    public virtual TFooTarget SomeFooTarget { get;set; }
}

public class GTeamPolicy : FooBasePolicy<GTeamTarget>
{
    public GTeamPolicy()
    {
        SomeFooTarget = new GTeamTarget();
    }
}

public class MTeamPolicy : FooBasePolicy<MTeamTarget>
{
    public GTeamPolicy()
    {
        SomeFooTarget = new MTeamTarget();
    }
}
```

And then I tried to use these this way,

problem is I don't know upfront which TeamTarget it is. It can be G or M.

```
FooBasePolicy<FooTarget> policy = null;
if (something.Equals("GTEAM"))
{
    //This gives me an implicit conversion error. It can't cast.
    policy = FromBinary(type, funnelData.Data) as FooBasePolicy<FooTarget>;
}
else if (something.Equals("MTEAM"))
{
    policy = FromBinary(type, funnelData.Data) as FooBasePolicy<FooTarget>;
}
```

FromBinary actually returns a deserialized object.

But it perfectly can cast into `FooBasePolicy`. But then I miss `SomeFooTarget` property.

Any idea? Please help.

Comment: Your `as` won't work either because classes are not covariant. You need a interface with `IFooBasePolicy<in FooTarget>`

Comment: By analogy: Given `class A {...}` and `class B : A {...}`, `List<B>` is not an extension of `List<A>`. It's just different. The same applies to `FooBasePolicy`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I think you meant `IFooBasePolicy<out TFooTarget>`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I can see that you are replacing `in` and `out` back and forth. Since property is of type `T`, interface needs to be covariant, so `out` must be used.

Comment: Or as kiziu said, `IFooBasePolicy<out FooTarget>`, it all depends on how you plan to use `policy` (for reading or writing)

Comment: Can you guys add a detail answer with how do I need to change the implementation? If I have an interface like `IFooBasePolicy<out FooTarget>` how do i get the value of `SomeFooTarget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others said, just define an interface:

```
public interface IFooBasePolicy<out TFooTarget> {
       TFooTarget SomeFooTarget { get; }
}
```

The base class `FooBasePolicy` now looks like:

```
public class FooBasePolicy<TFooTarget> : IFooBasePolicy<TFooTarget> 
    where TFooTarget : FooTarget {
    public virtual TFooTarget SomeFooTarget { get; set; }
}
```

Later you can use the following cast:

```
policy = ((IFooBasePolicy<FooTarget>)FromBinary(something));
```

Short explanation:

- `FooBasePolicy<FooTarget>` is not a base class of `FooBasePolicy<GTeamTarget>`
- this can be resolved with [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#C.23_examples): `GTeamTarget` is a subtype of `FooTarget`, therefore `FooBasePolicy<GTeamTarget>` is a subtype of `FooBasePolicy<FooTarget>`
- but covariance is only allowed on interfaces in `C#`
- so you need an interface with a coveriant type declaration

Comment: I tried it with `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary`, so I added `[Serializable]` to the classes.